# ParametricPlot3D with tube and arrow

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

I have this:

```
f[x_, y_] = x y/(x^2 + y^2);
ParametricPlot3D[{t, 2 t, f[t, 2 t]}, {t, -1/2, Sqrt[0.002]},
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick]] /. Line -> Tube
```

Which works, but I would like an arrowhead at the end of the tube. What do I have to add?

And maybe I want the arrow of the tube? I do want a three dimensional tubular arrowhead which is normally done with Graphics3d[{Arrow[Tube[ ....

**Difficulty with Composition:**

```
f[x_, y_] = x y/(x^2 + y^2);
Show[
 Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5],
  MeshStyle -> Opacity[0.5],
  MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, z}, z],
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 > 0.01],
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"},
  ViewPoint -> {2.3, -2.4, 0.7}],
 ParametricPlot3D[{t, 2 t, f[t, 2 t]}, {t, -1/2, -Sqrt[0.002]}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thickness[0.02]]] /. 
  Line -> Composition[Arrow, Tube],
 Graphics3D[{
   Blue, Arrow[Tube[{{1, 0, 0}, {0.1, 0, 0}}, 0.02]],
   Blue, Arrow[Tube[{{0, -1, 0}, {0, -0.1, 0}}, 0.02]]
   }]
 ]
```

Which produces:

[image]

Apparently, I can't control the thickness this way?

**Difficulty with Graphics3D Method:**

```
f[x_, y_] = x y/(x^2 + y^2);
Show[
 Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5],
  MeshStyle -> Opacity[0.5],
  MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, z}, z],
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 > 0.01],
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"},
  ViewPoint -> {2.3, -2.4, 0.7}],
 Graphics3D[{
   Blue, Arrow[Tube[{{1, 0, 0}, {0.1, 0, 0}}, 0.02]],
   Blue, Arrow[Tube[{{0, -1, 0}, {0, -0.1, 0}}, 0.02]],
   Red, Arrowheads[.04], 
   Arrow[Tube[
     Table[{t, 2 t, 
       f[t, 2 t]}, {t, -1/2, -Sqrt[0.002]}], .02], {0, -0.1}]
   }]
 ]
```

Which produces:

[image]

For some reason, the red arrow is not showing up. **My Bad: Turns out I had only one point produced by my table.**

Comment: Use `Composition[Arrow, Tube]` instead in the replacement rule.

Comment: Change `Tube` to `Arrow@*Tube`

Comment: Also the same, change the replacement rule by `/. Line[x__] :> Arrow[Tube[x]]`

Comment: @Szabolcs Could you please comment, what does this construct `@* ` do?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch In version 10 and later, `f @* g` is short for `Composition[f,g]`.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. All, I've tried your Composition method. It works, but for some reason I cannot control the thickness. See the example in my updated post.

Comment: `Table[{t, 2 t, f[t, 2 t]}, {t, -1/2, -Sqrt[0.002]}]` produces `{{-(1/2), -1, 2/5}}`, a single point. You can't make a tube from that. Try something like `Table[{t, 2 t, f[t, 2 t]}, {t, -1/2, -Sqrt[0.002], .05}]`

Comment: After a little experimenting I have found that `Red, Arrowheads[.04], Arrow[
 Tube[Table[{t, 2 t, f[t, 2 t]}, {t, -1/2, -Sqrt[0.004], .03}], .017], {0, -0.075}]` gives a more satisfactory red arrow. Producing a good looking tubular arrow requires fiddling -- it's more of an art than a science.

Comment: @m_goldberg. Yep, my fault. I didn't realized I had only one point. Nice analysis. However, this raised another issue for me. When using Matlab, I had a command linespace(a,b,n), which would create n points between a and b, but the resulting collection of points had as its first entry the number a, and as its last entry the number b. Clearly, the Table command does not do this. Is there an option to the table command that does this, or is there another command in Matlab that I am not aware of that will mimic Matlab's linespace(a,b,n) command?

Comment: Yes there is such a form, and now that I realize you working with a ruled surface, I would recommend `Arrow[Tube[Table[{t, 2 t, f[t, 2 t]}, {t, {-1/2, -Sqrt[0.004]}}], .017], {0, -0.05}]` -- I have updated my answer to show this single segment, tubular arrow on your full plot.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My experiments with this question indicate that something more than simple composition of `Arrow` and `Tube` is needed. What I came up with is

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t], Sin[t], t/4}, {t, 0, 2 π},
  PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[{Red, Arrowheads[.08]}]] /. 
  Line[pts_] :> Arrow[Tube[pts, .04], {0, -.1}]
```

which produces

[image: plot]

Of course, this can also be reproduced directly and I think even more easily, with `Graphics3D`.

```
Graphics3D[{
  Red, Arrowheads[.08], 
  Arrow[Tube[Table[{Cos[t], Sin[t], t/4}, {t, 0, 2 π, π/20}], .04], {0, -.1}]}]
```

[image: graphics]

#### Update

Now that the OP has given us a definition of `f`, I can work with his real problem, for which I recommend

```
f[x_, y_] = x y/(x^2 + y^2);

Show[
  Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
    PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5], 
    MeshStyle -> Opacity[0.5], 
    MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, z}, z], 
    RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 > 0.01], 
    AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, 
    ViewPoint -> {2.3, -2.4, 0.7}], 
  Graphics3D[{
    Blue, Arrow[Tube[{{1, 0, 0}, {0.1, 0, 0}}, 0.02]], 
          Arrow[Tube[{{0, -1, 0}, {0, -0.1, 0}}, 0.02]],
    Red, Arrowheads[.04], 
         Arrow[
           Tube[
             Table[{t, 2 t, f[t, 2 t]}, {t, {-1/2, -Sqrt[0.004]}}], 
             .017], 
           {0, -0.05}]}],
  ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: For some reason, my arrow is not showing up in my image. See the updated example in my original post.

Comment: If you play with aspectration and boxratios of the ParametricPlot3d you will get a deformed/stretched out tube.